# duplicated python installation

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using MacBook Pro with Maverick updated to El Capitan. The original python 2.7.5 is in `/usr/bin/python`. I tried to brew install vmtk (in `/usr/local/bin/vmtk`) yesterday and brew also installed another python for me, 2.7.11 in `/usr/local/bin/python`.

I tried "vmtk &" for the pypepad and it showed python error of

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I think I messed up the paths so I have no idea at all for a better next step. How can I install Tkinter for the 2.7.11 in `/usr/local/bin/python` ?

Comment: it should be import tkinter, you second python shouldn't have conflicts with builtin one

Comment: I suggest you installing `virtualenv`  which is a virtual environment tool for python, you can install multiple python versions without touching your OS built-in python. check it here http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: The brew-installed vmtk searches for interpreter in /usr/local/bin, but the brew-installed python shows _tkinter import err. Is there way to change the interpreter vmtk uses, or install tkinter for the brew-installed python?